# Why Are Methods Not Found In Authenticatable? Using Laravel 6 Cashier 10 With Stripe API?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Why are methods not found in Authenticatable? Im using Laravel 6 Cashier 10 with Stripe API. Please see the following errors in my Subscription Controller.

```
 Method 'createSetupIntent' not found in \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null 

 Method 'addPaymentMethod' not found in \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null 

 Unhandled \Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException
```

The above errors show in up in PHP storm. When the code is actually ran in the browser, I get this error: ... This makes sense considering PHP Storm cant find my methods. What do you guys think?

```
 This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method.
```

Here is my User model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use  Billable, Notifiable;


    protected $connection = 'mongodb';


     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'phone',
    ];
/**
* The collection name
*
* @var array
*/
protected $collection = 'users';



/**
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

Comment: post your `User` model please.

Comment: @HafezDivandari Yes, I will add my User model to the question.